# how to use a pointer to member function inside a static member function in c++

Tags: c++, static, function-pointers

I'm actually trying to use a pointer inside a static function which is in the same class as the functions that i'm trying to use inside the pointer.
I'm actually asked to use the class like this :

```cpp
class Factory {
    public:
        Factory() = default;
        ~Factory() = default;
        static IOperand* createOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string& value);
    private:
        IOperand* createInt8(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createInt16(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createInt32(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createFloat(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createDouble(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createBigDecimal(const std::string& value);
};
```

This is how I would do if this function wasn't static :

```cpp
IOperand* Factory::createOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string& value)
{
    IOperand* (Factory::*ptr[6])(const std::string&) = {
            &Factory::createInt8,
            &Factory::createInt16,
            &Factory::createInt32,
            &Factory::createFloat,
            &Factory::createDouble,
            &Factory::createBigDecimal
    };
    return (*this.*ptr[type])(value);
}
```

ps: eOperandType is just an enum

Comment: miss a parenthesis `((*this).*ptr[type])(value)` or `(*this->*ptr[type])(value)`.

Comment: and when the function *is* static, which object do you want to use to call the method?

Comment: is it possible that all methods of `Factory` should be static?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using pointers to member functions in this situation, instead of std::function ?

Comment: @AndyNewman I'd rather ask: Is there a particular reason to use `std::function`? `std::function` is for type erasure, but when all callables are of same type there is no need to erase the type

Comment: Just replace `this.*` with `ptr.*`, where `ptr` is a pointer to the object that you want to call the member function on.

Comment: I'm concerned that your factory functions return `IOperand*` which implies they `new` and object and return a pointer to it. This is an outdated strategy that should not be used anymore. Read about `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`. Your return type should be `std::unique_ptr<IOperand>`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number my instinctive future proofing in case I want to use a lambda here next year, but since this is not an exposed interface my instinct is irrelevant. You make a fair comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter where you use the member function pointer to call a method, you need an object to do so. In your "This is how I would do if this function wasn't static" version you call the method on the current object `this`. In the static method, you need a different object of type `Factory`, because there is no `this` in the static method. I suspect that actually all methods of `Factory` should be `static`, though not touching that, you can do this:

```
struct IOperand {};
class Factory {
    public:
        Factory() = default;
        ~Factory() = default;
        static IOperand* createOperand(size_t type, const std::string& value) {
            Factory f;
            IOperand* (Factory::*ptr[6])(const std::string&) = {
                &Factory::createInt8,
                &Factory::createInt16,
                &Factory::createInt32,
                &Factory::createFloat,
                &Factory::createDouble,
                &Factory::createBigDecimal
            };
            return (f.*ptr[type])(value);
        }
    private:
        IOperand* createInt8(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createInt16(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createInt32(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createFloat(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createDouble(const std::string& value);
        IOperand* createBigDecimal(const std::string& value);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know where is the object whose member function should be invoked.

It doesn't matter how you know it, the point is that you have to know it, in some form or fashion. Perhaps a pointer to the object gets passed as an additional parameter:

```cpp
IOperand* Factory::createOperand(Factory *obj, eOperandType type, const std::string& value)
{
    IOperand* (Factory::*ptr[6])(const std::string&) = {
            &Factory::createInt8,
            &Factory::createInt16,
            &Factory::createInt32,
            &Factory::createFloat,
            &Factory::createDouble,
            &Factory::createBigDecimal
    };
    return ((*obj).*ptr[type])(value);
}
```

Or, perhaps, a reference to the object gets passed in, instead of a pointer (resulting in a slight adjustment to the code), or maybe the object is somewhere else entirely. Maybe `createOperand()` calls some other function that returns a pointer or a reference to the instance of its class, but the point is that a member function cannot be invoked by itself. An object is required whose member function gets invoked. That's what a member function is, and how it differs from an ordinary function.

P.S. It doesn't matter whether all of this is "inside a static member function", or not. This is not a factor. The only factor is that inside a non-static member you always have `this` as an object that's available to you. But there is no law that requires you to invoke `this`'s member, via a pointer. If you have some other instance of the same class, somewhere, you can invoke its member function, instead of `this` one's.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers
I have now a better understanding of this subject and my project work.